# Creating a subset of a table using unique columns

Tags: sql

Table1:

```
+-----+---------+---------+-------------+
  ID  |  Val1   |  Val2   |   Date
+-----+---------+---------+-------------+
   1  |   10    |   11    |  2015-05-10
   2  |   10    |   11    |  2015-05-17
   3  |   10    |   11    |  2015-05-23
   4  |   9     |   17    |  2015-08-10
   5  |   9     |   17    |  2015-08-15
+-----+---------+---------+-------------+
```

Table2

```
+-----+---------+---------+-------------+
  ID  |  Val1   |  Val2   |   Date
+-----+---------+---------+-------------+
   3  |   10    |   11    |  2015-05-23
   5  |   9     |   17    |  2015-08-15
+-----+---------+---------+-------------+
```

I would like to write some SQL that will allow me to go from `Table1` to `Table2`. `Table2` is the subset of `Table1` with only the most recent date for any unique pair of Val1 and Val2.

To get the unique combinations of Val1 and Val2 that I need from `Table1` I can use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Val1, Val2  
FROM Table1
```

The part that I am stuck on selecting the subset from Table 1 using the unique combinations.  If I do the following, it will obviously return all of the results from Table1:

```
SELECT Val1, Val2, Date
FROM Table1
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT DISTINCT Val1, Val2 FROM Table1)
```

If I select distinct on all values including Date it will also return them all.  Does anyone have some insight to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this one:

```
select max(id), val1, val2, max(Date) from table1
group by Val1, Val2
```

Comment: This assumes that for the rows with distinct values of `val1` and `val2`, the row with the largest `Date` value also has the largest `ID` value.  The example data shows this to be true, but the OP didn't mention any data relationship like that was enforced. So depending on the situation this might give an erroneous `ID` value, but we can't know without more info in the question.